# React router v5 history push updates url but no rerender of component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, history.js

I am using history from react-router-dom v5 this works on home page, on the inside pages the history push does not work.

The URL in the browser is update, but the component or page is refreshed

**ListComponent.js**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const ListComponent () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleClick = () => {
        history.push("/list/view-all");
    }

    return(
        <button onClick={handleClick}>View All List</button>
    );
}
```

**ListViewAllComponent.js**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { ListComponent } from './ListComponent';

export const ListViewAllComponent() => {
    return(
        ...
        some other html codes
        ...
        <ListComponent />
    );
}
```

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
return (
     <Router>
         <Switch>
             .....
             <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentName} />
             ....
         </Switch>
     </Router>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? There's not enough to say why anything is or isn't working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: updated the question more relevant example

Comment: What is, or where, is rendering `ListViewAllComponent`? Is it within the router? What route is rendering `"/list/view-all"`? What is the component on *that* path that you say isn't being rendered?

Comment: `ListViewAllComponent` is within the router which is declared inside app.js for routes

Comment: And about the `"/list/view-all"` path.... is there a route rendering anything for it?

Comment: okay, in  the home page there is `ListComponent` which has 5 items (5 images) and with an view all button, on click on view all `/list/view-all` will push the history and render `ListViewAllComponent`

Comment: Ok, I feel like I'm pulling teeth here. Can you just provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't have to play 20 questions to get one snippet of code/information at-a-time?

Answer (score 0):

history.push () must be written in a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  history.push("/name");
}, [])
```

Or you can use the `<Redirect to = "/" />` component